# Can we set Default location for File Upload Control browse button

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload

I have `File Upload control` and when i click on browse button a `dialog box` appears from where we can select files as shown below:

[image]

But everytime i browse it goes to the location `C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\`. Instead i want a different location like `C:\Program Files\`.when clicked on browse button.

How this should be done?

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: FileUpload control of DotNet...and yes for time being i have used firefox..

Comment: I don't think this is controllable by the upload control, but rather from the browser.

Comment: See this discussion: [Default folder for the FileUpload Control](http://codeverge.com/asp.net.web-forms/set-initial-directory-in-fileupload/407403). It seems it's not possible, due to security concerns.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to achieve this. As stated **[here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1722893.aspx?Default%20path%20for%20Browse%20button%20in%20File%20Upload%20Control)**

> You are wanting to control the directory location that the browse starts in and not the save path the file is uploaded to, correct? I could be wrong but since the server never knows the file structure of the client machine, the developers of that control probably did not provide for that functionality

Answer (score 0):

This sample code might be helpfull to you

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

process.StartInfo.FileName = @"explorer";

process.StartInfo.Arguments = @" ";

Process.Start(@"c:\windows\"); //your file path here
```