# Use javascript to change the browse file path

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning javascript. Can I use javascript to change the browse file path when input type is file?

```
<input type="file" id="file_input" name="file_name"/>
```

When I click the "browse file..." button, the window is my assign path.
I do not hope the user to find the file location from the window. I am sorry my poor English

Comment: What is your question? The user chooses the file...

Comment: I think it normally starts at the same folder that the user used the last time they did an upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026059/can-we-set-default-location-for-file-upload-control-browse-button) for a more complete explanation, but basically it's a security issue. Code from your web page should not be allowed to know anything about the file structure on a client machine.

Comment: OK, I actually have searched the relevant question,  but I still want to ask in the stack overflow myself.